# What are my new connections on 4-way light switch?

Tags: light, multiway-switch

Swapping out all my switches and have been good with singles and 3-way but just stumbled across a 4-way. My confusion now is it has ground screw and 4 brass screws (no dark). White wires on one side and red wires on other. Went to buy replacement and on new one I see 2 brass screws, 2 black screws and 1 ground screw. Each side has one brass and one black so same configuration as current old switch is not possible. Unsure what my new connection would be and if this new switch is even the right one. [image: ssidenewide photo]

Answer (score 2):

By definition, the white and red wires are traveler pairs, based on their cables. The black wires are likely connected together.

One pair red /white on brass screws. The other pair on black screws.

Answer (score 1):

4-way switches come in a number of different wiring configurations. You have white travelers and red travelers. Pick a color wire and screw both to the brass terminals. The other color goes to the black screws.

Comment: Okay thanks. I was nervous since I read that both red and black wires could hot so thoughts red wires needed more specific placement like blacks would.

Comment: @CourtneyK  good for you for reading and being nervous... and for taking pictures before disconnecting the switch. In this case, the white and red take turns being hot so power has to be off when working on the switch.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @Courtney the wire colors don't mean anything at all on 3/4 way circuits. Any or every wire could be hot, depending on the switch wiring.